# graphing non sequential data C# and mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, graph

I'm trying to display in a graph (Winforms/C#) the total amount from one column vs unit of time (in this case month) - so it would be a amount vs time graph.  The problem is that the user would like the freedom of lets say - choosing the totals for January and June and compare them in a single graph (so the total for the month of January would be represented as a bar next to June's total's bar). I already capture the selected months (also, I have the graph control on the for) within a list but where I am really stuck is to build the mysql statement and its something like this

```
selectdataforGraph = "SELECT SUM(Amount_Net) AS Total FROM testingproject.incomeinformation WHERE date";

foreach (int month in selectedMonth) {
   selectdataforGraph +=  "between '" + selected_year+ "-" + month + 
   "'-1 AND '" + selected_year + "-"+month+ "-31' AND";
}
```

I know it has some space missing and some quotation mark problems - already ran the query and I figured as much but I don't think the in-between would work because I don't know how to `AND` the next part of it so if a user picks May then August would be between 2007-5-01 and 2007-5-30 AND 2007-8-01 and 2007-8-30???

Comment: You want to use parameterized queries.  Building SQL strings opens your program up to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: OK , I know that but I am trying to figure out the general logic behind the adding the next month data to the query then I accommodate it to parameters

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: didn't seem MySQL was your DB...**

Definitely use a parameterized query!   However... to fit in with what you have and so you can test it quickly...

I think I would use DATEPART rather than BETWEEN....

```
    var selectdataforGraph = "SELECT SUM(Amount_Net) AS Total FROM testingproject.incomeinformation WHERE ";
    var monthList = string.Join(",", selectedMonth);
    selectdataforGraph += " YEAR(date) = " + selected_year;
    selectdataforGraph += " AND MONTH(date) in (" + monthList + ")";
```

Comment: I tried it and it works but this just gives me the total amount for both months selected as one. i want to keep the sum as separate totals so i can then display the totals within their respective months. Maybe something like this? : SELECT SUM(Amount_Net) AS TotalMonthA, SUM(Amount_Net) as TotalMonthB FROM testingproject.incomeinformation WHERE YEAR(date) = 2007 AND MONTH(date) in (5,6).  I am thinking of just making another table that keeps tracks of the totals per month per year and then just query that table so the sum part of the select is taken out.

Comment: Heh... only having one SUM() as Total misled me...  you'll need to do a group by MONTH(date) if you want to do it that way which will give you one row for each year / month combination.  There is another way to do it in columns but it's significantly more difficult SQL.

Comment: Yeah, was my bad for using a bad variable name >.< anyways thanks for your help but i think i will go with the new table - that way the query will go straight to the one table which already has the totals and just have to display it with ease since the table already has it by month and totals and just could use the one you originally posted with minor tweaks.  I would mark this as answered but it tells me i have not the rating for it yet.... thank you

Comment: Sorry, what wasn't letting me was answer my own question >.<